# cannot read the property of undefined

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I am coding a server-side app in node JS and I am using a database in MySQL.

I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'activated' of undefined"

The request I do should say "empty set" when I do it manually in the MySQL terminal.

When I try to use it in my code an I input and invalid discord_key, it returns an error, but I want it to return just a false alarm so I can catch it and use that info.

```
function checkKey(key) {
    var activated = "";
    var sqlcheck = "SELECT activated from authentification where discord_ key = ?";
    console.log("in function");
    DB.query(sqlcheck, [key], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw (err);
        activated = result[0].activated;
    });
    if (!activated) {
        console.log("null");
        return ("NULL");
    } else {
        console.log("used");
        return ("used");
    }
}
```

I should get :

that request sends an empty set, so the key doesn't exist.

thank you for your help!

Comment: If you `console.log(result)` what does it show you? If `result` is an empty array (empty set) then item at index 0 is undefined. Therefore it does not have the property activated.

Comment: i get [] with the console.log(result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Error**

The error is telling you that a variable you are using is undefined. It tells you this because you attempt to read a property from an undefined variable.

You mentioned `result` is an empty array. This means that any index you attempt to access returns `undefined`. For example:

```
let result = []
console.log(result[0] === undefined) // prints true
```

And in javascript, if you try and access a property of `undefined`, you get your error. Continuing our example:

```
result[0].activated // Throws error: Cannot read property 'activated' of undefined.
```

Since there is no guarentee that `result[0]` has a value, you should make sure it is not `undefined` before accessing it's properties. As @NipunChawla shows, one way is to check the array has a length (i.e at lease one value):

```
if (result.length) { // Does result have values?
  activated = result[0].activated
} else {
  activated = false
}
```

Better yet, if you know you are working with `result[0]` only, check whether it is defined directly:

```
if (result[0]) { // Does result[0] have a value?
  activated = result[0].activated
} else {
  activated = false
}
```

You are still left with the possibility that `result[0].activated` does not exist. Meaning `activated` would be `undefined`.

```
if (result[0] && result[0].activated) { // ... and does the first value
                                        // contain the property activated?
  activated = result[0].activated
} else {
  activated = false
}
```

So all together now:

```
DB.query(sqlcheck, [key], function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw (err);
  if (result[0] && result[0].activated) {
    activated = result[0].activated
  } else {
    activated = false
  }
})
```

**Async Callbacks**

To fix `!activated` in the second if statement always being `true`, you should look into how callbacks work. Basically `DB.query` goes off and does its thing. When it is done, it will execute the function you provided it as a callback. The order of execution looks something like this:

1. Call `DB.query` to send a request to your database
2. Continue execution of your script. i.e check `if (!activated) { ...`
3. `DB.query` has now finished and calls your callback, assigning `activated = result[0].activated`. i.e `function(err, result)`

A quick way you could fix this would be like so:

```
function checkKey(key) {
  var activated = "";
  var sqlcheck = "SELECT activated from authentification where discord_ key = ?";
  console.log("in function");
  DB.query(sqlcheck, [key], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw (err);
    if (result[0] && result[0].activated) {
      activated = result[0].activated
    } else {
      activated = false
    }

    doSomethingWithResult(activated)
  });
}

function doStuffWithResult(activated) {
  if (!activated) {
    console.log("null");
    // Do your !activated stuff
  } else {
    console.log("used");
    // Do your activated stuff
  }
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) question for more info.

Comment: thank you for this detailed explination. So if I understand correctly, I check this answer when I do the DB request ?

Comment: I still don't understand something. When I put a "discord_key" that is in my DB, it goes in my if (!activated). But when I put a random key that is not in my DB, I get the same thing. in the first case, activated = 'false' but in the 2nd case activate = undefine.
Why does it still prints me : "null" ? it sould print me used for a key that doesn't exist

Comment: @luckysimon That has to do with javascript and asynchronous callbacks. I'll update my answer with an explanation.

Comment: thank you. Yes I was looking at those earlier but it is hard to understand.

Comment: ok So i seperate my function into 2. I'll have a look. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

In case no result you can write this:

```
if (err) throw (err);
activated = result.length ? result[0].activated : false;
```

That will return false in case of no result.

Comment: Thank you that worked. (well still need to correct some code). could you please explain to me what this line do? I don't really understand

Comment: This is a conditional statement it will work like if there is an element is an array then it will return the length of that array otherwise it will return false.

Comment: It is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)